# Find all census tracts N miles from a lat, lon point

Tags: r, census

Using R, I'd like to find all census tracts within a given distance of a point (lon,lat).

i.e. All census tracts within 20 miles of 34.0522, 118.2428

I have used the sp library and over command to locate the tract of a given point, but would like to use it to find all the tracts covered by a "disc".

Ideas?

Comment: Does "covered by a disc" mean *wholly contained within the disc" or "intersecting the disc"?

Comment: The end goal is all census tracts within N miles of a point.  So, I assume that every tract touched by any part of the dist is included

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [rgeos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) library. You could use the gIntersects function as well as gBuffer to create your "disc".

Roughly:

```
    library(rgeos)

    con <- url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/CHE_adm2.RData")
    print(load(con))
    close(con)

    pt1 = readWKT("MULTIPOINT(8.5 47)") # some location
    buf = gBuffer(pt1, width=0.2)  # the "disc" - width is in projection units
    proj4string(buf) = proj4string(gadm)

    intersects = gIntersects (buf, gadm, byid=TRUE) 
    selection = subset(gadm, as.vector(intersects))

    plot (gadm)
    plot (selection, add=T, col="red") 
    plot (buf, add=T, lwd = 3)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I have the shape files from the us census and use the "over" command in R to find the specific tract for a given point.  How would I integrate that shape file into your proposed solution?  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my code above to correspond more closely to your question. Based on your answer to the comment above I have also used the gIntersects function here. You can use the byid=True option to loop through the polygons in your SpatialPolygons object (which I assume you generated from your original shape file when reading it into R).